# ASP .NET call button click from Javascript or JQuery

Tags: vb.net

I have a button in a page:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnOpening" runat="server" Text="Locale" OnClientClick="TipologiaMenuClick('1')"                                                    AutoPostBack="False" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Clicking this button calls a javascript:

```
    function TipologiaMenuClick(TipoMenu)
    {

       ...
       some things
       ...

        var BtnRefreshMenuList = document.getElementById('MainContent_BtnRefreshMenuList')
        if (BtnRefreshMenuList != null)
        {
            alert('1');
            BtnRefreshMenuList.click();             
            alert('2');
        }               
    }
```

BtnRefreshMenuList is a button calling a procedure in the backend.

With FireFox I see the first alert, then the backend is called (I have a breackpoint there).

With Edge or Chrome, I see the first alert, the backend is NOT called, and I see the second alert.

I tried with JQuery

```
$("#MainContent_BtnRefreshMenuList").click();
```

but nothing changes: all ok with FireFox, nothings works with Edge or Chrome.

Any suggestion?

Edit 28/07 10:08:
I have new informations:

I tried with a double call:

```
$("#MainContent_BtnRefreshMenuList").click();

setTimeout(function () { $("#MainContent_BtnRefreshMenuList").click() }, 50);
```

The first call works with FireFox, I found the second call as a suggestion online, and SHOULD work for other browsers.

In different PCs and different virtual machines I see different behaviours.
In a virtual machine Windows 7 the page works with Firefox, Edge, Chrome, in another virrtual machine with Windows 7 the page works only with Firefox.
In my physical PC Windows 10 the page works with all browsers.

I removed all internet data, cookies included, but nothing changes.

This thing is driving me CRAZY.

Edit 28/07 11:12:

browser compatibility is bettere with

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#MainContent_BtnRefreshMenuList").click() }, 10);
```

and even better with

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#MainContent_BtnRefreshMenuList").click() }, 5);
```

It seems related with the timeout: with 5 milliseconds the page works well with a lot of browsers, from Windows, Iphone, Android.

Comment: Is BtnRefreshMenuList in an update panel? Otherwise I would expect the call to the backend to cause the whole form to postback

Comment: No, in this page I don't use updatepanel.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click you correctly simulated the click event with that call.. so there's something fishy going on. The timeout variant also was totally crazy. Why should it make any difference if called few ms later.

Comment: Edited with other informations

Comment: This may be a security issue. I came across a problem a little while ago where the browser treated something as a user interaction if it happened quickly enough after a user clicked something, otherwise it was treated as not done by the user, and (in this case) the newly opened window was treated as a popup and blocked. I can't see anything wrong with your code. Do you really need the timeout at all? Could this be a threading issue?

Comment: I can confirm your issue. I can reproduce it in Chrome. I'm going to find a fix for you now. This affects some of my projects too.

Comment: OK - further testing shows that although the 2nd alert is shown, the postback does happen. I'll post my test code below with screen-shots.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your situation as simply as I can. Clicking the button does not prevent the 2nd alert from showing, but once you dismiss the 2nd alert it will do the postback, providing you don't lose focus on Chrome for any reason. If you lose focus then the postback won't happen, and the alerts are auto-dismissed. This must be a Chromium thing.

**Initial state:**

[image]

**After clicking: "Trigger back end post through JS ..."**

[image]

**After dismissing the alert**

[image]

**Finally**

[image]

HOWEVER, if I minimise Chrome before dismissing either alert, the postback will never happen.

Here is the ASPX code

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ClickButtonTest.aspx.vb" Inherits="Scrap.ClickButtonTest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function backEndPostBack() {
            var button = document.getElementById("btn_BackEndPost")
            if (typeof button !== 'undefined') {
                alert("Going to click the button.");
                button.click();
                button.value = "I've been clicked";
                alert("Should never reach this alert because of the postback.")
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:backEndPostBack();">Trigger back end post through JS (will click the button below)</a><br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_BackEndPost" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="I've not been clicked" />
            <asp:Literal ID="lit_PostbackStatus" runat="server" >No postback has happened yet...</asp:Literal>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the VB.NET code

```
Public Class ClickButtonTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_BackEndPost_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_BackEndPost.Click
        lit_PostbackStatus.Text = "btn_BackEndPost_Click was fired on the server..."
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: In my situation the only wsay is a very short tiomeout. Of course in the real page I don't usa alerts, they a re there only to see something. And the second alert should never appear. When it appears, the backend is not called.

Comment: @GiorgioForti can you confirm whether if you reproduce the code I provided above you get the postback? It is probably best not to use timeouts at all. `$("#id").click();` should always do the trick. Unless it's a `LinkButton` - in which case you will need to call `$("#id")[0].click();`